# Pull instagram photos and upload to my domain?

Tags: php, instagram

I would like to have a cronjob or the like run a script to pull my instagram photos to a folder on my domain. Has anyone done such a thing? Something like Instaport, but have it automated on my site?

I logged into the dev area on instagram and looked at some of the options, but get lost looking at the API. I haven't done much with an API.

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hire a developer - does this thought count?

Comment: Have you heard of If This Then That?  Maybe it can do that type of thing for you?  http://ifttt.com/channels

Comment: @zerkms all thoughts count. So thanks!

Comment: @jjathman That looks promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty solution I used once:

Fetch all your photos from Instagram using the API: There are some php classes out there you can use, for example: http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/login-with-instagram-php.html

Grab the URL's of all your images

Make a script that stores these in a folder on your server. You can use something like this

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($url); // Return info about the URL
$image = ($path_parts['basename']); // Save file name in a variable
mkdir("folderName/", 0700); // Create the folder
copy($url,"folderName/".$image); // Copy files to folder
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem. I'm not experienced at all but it worked fine for me!